# Isometry and integral over manifold

Tags: integration, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold, $(U,\varphi), (V,\psi)$ be two charts and $\phi:U\rightarrow V$ be some isometry. I would like to prove the formula
$$\int_Vf dV_g=\int_U(f\circ\phi)dVg$$

I tried to prove this formula through the definition of the integral as follows:
\begin{align*}
\int_Vf dV_g&=\int_{\psi(V)}f(\psi^{-1}(x))\sqrt{\det g(\partial_i \psi,\partial_j\psi)_{\vert\psi^{-1}(x)}} dx\\
&= \int_{\varphi(U)}(f\circ\phi)(\varphi^{-1}(x))\cdot \sqrt{\det(d(\tilde{\phi})_x)}\sqrt{\det g(\partial_i \psi,\partial_j\psi)_{\vert\psi^{-1}(\tilde{\phi}x)}} dx,
\end{align*}
where I have used for the last equality the common substitution rule for euclidean space with respect to the diffeomorphism $\tilde{\phi}:=\psi\circ\phi\circ \varphi^{-1}.$

What remains to show is the very complicated looking identity:

$$\sqrt{\det(d(\tilde{\phi})_x)}\sqrt{\det g(\partial_i \psi,\partial_j\psi)_{\vert\psi^{-1}(\tilde{\phi}x)}}=\sqrt{\det g(\partial_i \varphi,\partial_j\varphi)_{\vert\varphi^{-1}(x)}}$$

I could not prove this equality yet. Can someone give me an idea how to attack this problem?

Best wishes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\phi$ is an isometry so $|det(d\phi)|=1$
We have 
$$\int_V fdV_g=\int_U (f\circ\phi) |det(\phi)| dV_g,$$

Comment: I do not understand how this helps… Could you please tell me what you had in mind?

Comment: @Braten, is the change of variable formula: http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis610/diffgeom4.pdf.